# Best way to store NSDate as NSString and then convert back from NSString to NSDate

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I need to convert an NSDate to an NSString and then take this NSString and convert it back to an NSDate with the full time and date - what is the best format to store this?

Comment: How are conversion and storage related?

Comment: You should explain why you want to convert the date to a string. Should the string be human readable? Is it only for serialization?

Comment: Do you also need locale information? Because that is not contained in an NSDate.

Comment: This must have been covered dozens of times on SO.  Did you search at all?

Comment: Why can\t you store it as NSDate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Convert to NSString,
first NSTimeInterval then create NSString object and do what you want.

Convert to NSDate,
first convert it to NSTimeInterval(double value) and create a NSDate object

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date]; 
//        convert to NSString
NSString *strValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", [date timeIntervalSince1970]]; 

//        convert to NSDate
date =  [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:[strValue doubleValue]];
```

Comment: So is this the best way to store date into string? `strValue` will contain milliseconds something as 1359031737.046572.  without dateformatter `full time and date`

Comment: @AnoopVaidya so we can use @"%lf"(long float) prefix instead of @"%f"

Comment: Be careful with this! I just ran into a situation where using this method to convert to a string (and then back) resulted in two dates that would not compare as equal. Possibly due to precision issues with the internal implementation?

As my code depends on being able to compare equality, I was forced to run my incoming NSDate objects through this conversion (both ways) in order to homogenize them so they would compare properly.